# Return Array of Unique Dates from Date Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

In our angularjs app we're receiving an array of dates that then need to be filtered out to only return an array full of unique dates (not strings). I tried some of the answers on SO but I think because I'm comparing dates and not strings - I'm yielding different results. Any help on what the best approach is would be very helpful. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, date equality is different from string equality. Dates are objects, and the `===` comparator for objects compares them by reference, not value. Since `{} === {}` in JS is `false`, two Dates will never be equal to each other. So, let's just turn the dates into numbers:

```js
let dates = [new Date(), new Date('1/1/11'), new Date('1/1/11'), new Date('1/4/66')]


let uniqueDates = dates
                   .map(s => s.getTime())
                   .filter((s, i, a) => a.indexOf(s) == i)
                   .map(s => new Date(s));
                   
console.log(uniqueDates);
```

The logic with `indexOf` is that every unique value should be present only at its own position; any others are duplicates (s is current item, i is current index, and a is the array itself). Then we map the array back into `Dates` and return it.

Comment: thank you - the refactor of your code was the cherry on top. I think I was overcomplicating before by dismissing the idea of converting to a string and then back to date

Comment: No problem! Come to think of it, it's more straightforward to replace `.toString()` with `.getTime()`. That returns the date as a simple number, epoch time. Cleaner and a little more efficient than comparing strings.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using lodash:

```
const date1 = new Date();
const date2 = new Date();
const arr = [date1, date1, date2, date2];
const uniqueDates = _.uniqBy(arr, date => date.getTime());
```

Uses `uniqBy` to ensure that we compare dates by their value and not just by object identity. See here: [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)